# How to convert a hex color in flutter they way I did in swift?

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

This is the code worked in swift. How to do the same in flutter?
I am new to flutter. How can I convert this code to flutter?

hexcolor='#4D0000FF';

```
extension UIColor {

public convenience init?(hex: String) {
 let r, g, b, a: CGFloat
    if hex.hasPrefix("#") {

        let start = hex.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
        let hexColor = String(hex[start...])
        if hexColor.count == 8 {
            let scanner = Scanner(string: hexColor)
            var hexNumber: UInt64 = 0

            if scanner.scanHexInt64(&hexNumber) {
                r = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0xff000000) >> 24) / 255
                g = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x00ff0000) >> 16) / 255
                b = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x0000ff00) >> 8) / 255
                a = CGFloat(hexNumber & 0x000000ff) / 255
                self.init(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
                return
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}}
```

Comment: Y'all are working too hard.  Just remove the '#', and use int.parse(someString, radix: 16);

Answer (score 0):

to convert Hex string to color in flutter:
try this

```
hexStringToColor(String hexColor) {
  hexColor = hexColor.toUpperCase().replaceAll("#", "");
  if (hexColor.length == 6) {
    hexColor = "FF" + hexColor;
  }
  return Color(int.parse(hexColor, radix: 16));
}
```

on your widget for example:

```
 Container(
   height: 50,
   color: hexStringToColor('#4D0000FF'),
   child: Center(
     child: Text("Hex color"),
   ),
 ),
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: But I have the color in the format say hexCode='#4D000000'

Comment: there is no `hexcode='#4D000000'`. do you mean `#4D0000`

Comment: see the code I have mentioned, hexcolor.count==8

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it:

```
extension HexColor on Color {
  /// String is in the format "aabbcc" or "ffaabbcc" with an optional leading "#".
  static Color fromHex(String hexString) {
    final buffer = StringBuffer();
    if (hexString.length == 6 || hexString.length == 7) buffer.write('ff');
    buffer.write(hexString.replaceFirst('#', ''));
    return Color(int.parse(buffer.toString(), radix: 16));
  }

  /// Prefixes a hash sign if [leadingHashSign] is set to `true` (default is `true`).
  String toHex({bool leadingHashSign = true}) => '${leadingHashSign ? '#' : ''}'
      '${alpha.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}'
      '${red.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}'
      '${green.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}'
      '${blue.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}';
}
```

Comment: what if the string is length 8? and did you use any package for it?

Comment: If the string is length 8, works also. I didn't use any package.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve as follows:

```
 class HexColor extends Color {
  static int _getColorFromHex(String hexColor) {
    hexColor = hexColor.toUpperCase().replaceAll("#", "");
    if (hexColor.length == 6) {
      hexColor = "FF" + hexColor;
    }
    return int.parse(hexColor, radix: 16);
  }

  HexColor(final String hexColor) : super(_getColorFromHex(hexColor));
}
```

And then call HexColor as:

```
  static Color buttonBlack = HexColor("#1C1C1C");
```